# Initializing objects in an array of interfaces based on object name in Java

Tags: java

I'm facing a challenge where I have an array of interfaces in Java, and I want to initialize the objects for these interfaces based on a specified name for each object. I've explored different approaches, but I'm looking for the most efficient way to solve this situation.

Here's a simplified example of my structure:

```
public interface Element{
   String name();
   //static method() to initialise object
}

public interface BackElements extends Element{

}

public class Wall(String name) implements BackElements{

}

public class Door(String name) implements BackElements{

}

void main(){
   Element element[] = new Element[2];
   element[0] = methode("WALL");
}
```

methode = static method that creates element based on string, like if I give the method name = WALL as string, it creates a Wall(..) class/

I was told to create this static method, but I don't know how. I am still new to Java.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but your classes don't implement the interface. And `public class Wall(String name){}` won't compile. Are you trying to use normal class or a record?

Comment: Anyway you need either reflection, or a factory (since you mention efficiency, you most likely need to go with this approach).

Comment: @Chaosfire sorry about that, i just updated the code. So it depends on the string i give sometimes the object is a record that implements BackElements and sometims its a class.

Comment: I think I would remove the interface and the class hierarchy, and just instantiate some type (maybe `Element`) with the properties it needs.  Until you can find a compelling reason to add the hierarchy back in, I think it's just design for the sake of design and seems to be getting in the way of the code you need to write.

Comment: @Chaosfire i know it wont compile i gave this classes just to give an idea of the issue i am facing

Comment: @markspace i am creating a 2D game so having theses interfaces is issential to keep the project clean (the project is kinda big so i'll let u imagine) the reason i am creating theses is that all the Elements have something in commun but some of them have specific methods.

Comment: I know it might seem that your game is large, but it probably really isn't.  Designs have to be adapted to the problem at hand.  Look at Entity Component System, it may be closer to what you really want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

Comment: @markspace Thats exactly what i am trying to do, i am suprised i've done it without knowing it existed, the only thing is the teachers (its a school project) banned us of inheriting a class which makes it a bit hard for me to do it otherwise. They said interfaces can inherit each other and classes implements these interfaces but we cant inherit a class do u have any idead how to do it without that ?

Comment: If this is a class project I would probably just instantiate (create) each type of object separately.  First create all the `Wall`s, then all the `Door`s, etc.  It's simpler and will get the job done.  An Entity Component System is rather sophisticated and used in large projects, it'll probably not meet your class work requirements for a hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide *static methods* from within the *BackElements* *interface*.

```java
interface Element {
    String name();
}

interface BackElements extends Element {
    static Wall ofWall(String name) {
        return new Wall(name);
    }

    static Door ofDoor(String name) {
        return new Door(name);
    }
}

record Wall(String name) implements BackElements {
}

record Door(String name) implements BackElements {
}
```

```java
Element[] a = new Element[2];
a[0] = BackElements.ofWall("abc");
a[1] = BackElements.ofDoor("xyz");
```